# PHPExcel formula & styling lost on closing file

Tags: php, phpexcel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using **PHPExcel** to create **dropdowns** on range of cells(eg: *A1:A100*) and styling them.

The export template has the formula for all the cells as expected. 
Ones I edit the file, ***save and close it***, I lose the formulas and styling on rest of the cells below the last entry. 
(eg: if A50 contains my last record, then I lose the validations and styling on the cells from A50:A100 on closing the file)

**Note**:
I am using laravel [maatwebsite](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs) excel library and LibreOffice to edit the xlsx files.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was an LibreOffice issue. File saved in excel format would cause the problem. Saved in .ods format and it worked.